# Ruby net/scp, upload file from variable

Tags: ruby, ssh, binary-data, scp

It seems like net/scp in Ruby (I'm using 1.8.7) only accepts a path and not binary data as "local_file" parameter.

In my case, I have the local file stored in a variable.
Am I required to save->upload->delete a local file, or is it possible to send the file "directly" to the remote server via SSH without temporary creating it locally?

I'm open to other solutions than SCP.
What I tried so far is using normal SSH and then executing

`echo 'binary here' > remote_file_name`

however I'm concerned about command length limits in Unix and I faced escaping problems and so forth...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it will interpret a string as a file name, it should recognise a StringIO object as actual data to upload.